# interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript not working when send string to html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I am trying to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript.
I want to interpolate the words_to_be_removed variable with the defaultMessageTest string.
I have tried the below 3 methods but none of them working.

1. `String text ${expression}`
2. "String text ${expression}"
3. "String text " + expression " String text"

```
function remove_alert_word(alert_word) {
    const words_to_be_removed = [alert_word];
    const defaultMessageTest = "Alert word ${words_to_be_removed} removed successfully!";
    channel.del({
        url: "/json/users/me/alert_words",
        data: {alert_words: JSON.stringify(words_to_be_removed)},
        success() {
            update_alert_word_status(
                $t({defaultMessage: defaultMessageTest}),
                false,
            );
        },
        error() {
            update_alert_word_status($t({defaultMessage: "Error removing alert word!"}), true);
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use backtick characters (`)

```
const defaultMessageTest = `Alert word ${words_to_be_removed} removed successfully!`;
```

```js
const test = 123;
console.log(`this is test${test}`)
```

Comment: backtick is giving an error.